# Select values from any column/row based on criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I have a correlation matrix in the form of a dataframe. Something like:

```
       xyz   abc  def
xyz    1     0.1  -0.2
abc    0.1   1    0.3
def    -0.2  0.3  1
```

I need to be able to select all values above or below a certain threshold, but of course they could be in any row or column.

For example, select all values which are above 0.2. There are two results:

(def,abc) and (abc,def)

Im not sure how to do this since it involves searching for values based on criteria in every row/column. Ideally the output should be in a format which easily identifies the pairs (eg: a list of tuples or something like that)

edit: oh, and of course all the identical column/rows would also be in the results of the above example (ie: xyz/xyz, abc/abc, def/def)

Comment: But isn't the value `1` not also above `0.2`? So you don't want to select that one?

Comment: I would go for looping first over line Horizontal, and in that loop you loop over the Vertical line.

Comment: I actually don't want those. However if they are included in a list of tuples, I can then filter them out at that point. The part that im struggling with is getting the values out of the dataframe.

Comment: Thanks, i've gone ahead and created the looping structure which does the trick. I was hoping for a vectorised way to do it without looping since that is generally faster (my dataframe is HUGE). However this at least works for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way using `np.triu` to mask out upper triangular matrix and reshaping correlation matrix by `stack`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# simulate some data to generate corr_mat
# ==============================================
np.random.seed(0)
data = np.random.multivariate_normal([0,0,0], [[1,0.1,-0.2],[0.1,1,0.3],[-0.2,0.3,1]], 10000)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns='xyz abc def'.split())
corr_mat = df.corr()
corr_mat

        xyz     abc     def
xyz  1.0000  0.1216 -0.1901
abc  0.1216  1.0000  0.3014
def -0.1901  0.3014  1.0000

# processing
# =======================================
# mask on lower-triangle only
mask = np.ones_like(corr_mat, dtype=np.bool)
mask[np.triu_indices_from(mask)] = False
mask

array([[False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False]], dtype=bool)

# reshape the correlation matrix, and select corr > 0.2
corr_stacked = corr_mat.stack()
corr_stacked[(corr_stacked > 0.2) & (mask.ravel())]

def  abc    0.3014
dtype: float64

# you can reset_index to put multi-level index to columns
```

Answer (score 1):

Flatten 2d to 1d tuples of ((row,col), val). Sort by val. retrieve (row,col) of tuples whose val > 0.2

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like it will work but im not sure how to get the 1d tuples ((row,col), val). I have tried list(df.itertuples())

Comment: to_dict(*args, **kwargs)  Convert DataFrame to dictionary.     http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your dataframe is "df" and your threshold is "value" you could do something like:

```
df[df>value] or
```

`df[df>value].dropna(axis=1, how="all")` if you want to remove columns with no matches.